# Finding records with equal values in different fields?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `people` table, two of this table fields are `id` and `country`.

I want to find all records that have the same `id` and `country`, because `id` should be unique per country.

What would be the right way do do that?

for example, sample output should be:

```
+--------------+---------+
| id           | country |
+--------------+---------+
| 123          | AT      |
| 123          | AT      |
| 456          | GB      |
| 456          | GB      |
| 456          | GB      |
| 789          | AU      |
| 789          | AU      |
```

Comment: Please add sample data (tables) and desired output

Comment: @DDS done, added example output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` clause will suffice:

```
SELECT id, country
FROM people
WHERE id <> "" AND id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id, country
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: this solution gives me also single fields..please see the example output that I added to the question

Comment: It will give you single fields, but those fields are repeated. In your example my query would return `123` and `AT`, `456` and `GB`, `789` and `AU`.

Comment: got you...you right, it would help if it was possible to exclude ```id != "" and id is not null```, i only interested when id actually have a number

Comment: I get Empty set . and tried ```elect * from suppliers where id = "123" and country = "FR";``` and found results of 2 records, so the query should find those :/ @Michał Turczyn

Comment: @JohnBigs Then replace `people` table with `suppliers`

Comment: i did, its not it, it was a typo here @Michał Turczyn

Comment: @JohnBigs I don't know how you are trying to run my query and what your real data looks like, but works perfectly on example you gave. So, if you are having problems, you should check your data, not the query

Comment: obviously you were right, im sorry it was my bad, accepted the answer. thanks! @Michał Turczyn

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT p1.* FROM people p1
    INNER JOIN people p2
    ON p1.id = p2.id AND p1.country = p2.country
    ORDERY BY p1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

this may work

```
 with cte as (SELECT id -- extracts ID for countryes present more than 1 time
FROM people
GROUP BY id, country
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

select id, country -- adds repeated values
from people p join cte on p.id=cte.id
```